# How can I find a problem in my Java code?

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to do homework for my IT classes and we just started programming a bit. We have 2 classes, Main and Okej. It is just a simple code where the getters and setters have to check if the user input the right number. But the IF statements just do not work.

```
package okej;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner program = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please, type your Name.");
        String name = program.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please, type your age.");
        int age = program.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please, type your weight.");
        double weight = program.nextDouble();


        Okej you = new Okej(name, age, weight);
        System.out.print(you);
    }

}
```

---

```
package okej;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Okej {

    String name = "";
    int age = 0;
    double weight = 0.0;

    public Okej(String name, int age, double weight) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        System.out.println("Okay, your name is " + name + ".");
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }


    public void setAge(int age) {
        if (age > 18) {
            if (age < 99) {
        this.age = age;
        System.out.println("Okay, your age is " + age + "."); 
        }
    }
        else {
            System.out.println("You have put an invalid age for this program.");
            System.out.println("Setting the number to 20.");
            this.age = 20;
        }

    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }   

    public void setWeight(double weight) {
        if (weight > 30) {
            if (weight < 300) {
        this.weight = weight;
        System.out.println("Okay, your weight is " + weight + "."); 
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("You have put an invalid weight for this program.");
            System.out.println("Setting the number to 50.");
            this.weight = 50;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Okay, your name is " + name + ", your age is " + age + ", and you weight "+ weight +".";
    }

}
```

Comment: you are not calling the setter any where.

Comment: Well this was easier than I thought.. thanks jalyn2.

Comment: By the way, when passing an age >= 99 to the setter, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because logic which validates your inputs are inside `setters` and you are not calling it. You are creating your object through constructor which doesn't execute any validation. You can do one of following:

- move validation codes to static method and call it in constructor to validate before assigning values
- use builders with validation code inside
- create empty object (with default constructor) and use setters to set values which will trigger your validation
  ...